# Equivalent forms of four fermion operators?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fermions, dirac-matrices

In [this](http://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7151) paper a little below equation (15) it is said that the four fermion operator

$$(q^{\dagger}\bar{\sigma}_{\mu}q)(u^{\dagger}\bar{\sigma}^{\mu}u)$$

where $q$ and $u$ are left chiral Weyl fermion fields is equivalent to

$$q^{\dagger}u^{\dagger}qu.$$

How is this equivalence proved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the property
$$
(\sigma^\mu)_{\alpha{\dot\alpha}} ({\bar \sigma}_\mu)^{{\dot \beta}\beta} = - 2 \delta_\alpha^\beta \delta_{\dot\alpha}^{\dot\beta}
$$